# How to convert KerasTensor to tf.tensor

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, onnx

When I use `tf.cast` and `tf.concat` op in `tensorflow 2.5`, they become `TFOpLambda`(but they are normal op in `tensorflow 2.3.1`). When I use `onnx2keras` to convert `squeezenet` the `concat` op becomes `TFOpLambda` in the `.h5` model. When I debug I see that the input type is `KerasTensor`, I think maybe the two ops can only accept `tf.tensor`, so how can I convert KerasTensor to `tf.Tensor`? Or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Is there any solution?